# Ошибка ли?

Tags: синтаксис

**Утром начался заезд и регистрация участников мероприятия.**
Вас ничего не смущает в построении предложения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По правилу стилистики, если сказуемое стоит перед однородными подлежащими, оно согласуется с ближайшим подлежащим. Поэтому *начался заезд и регистрация*, но *заезд и регистрация начались.*

Answer (score 0):

Вам хочется "начались"? Не знаю, тоже не здорово смотрится.

Comment: Регистрация-женский род.Разве можно сказать"начался регистрация" ?

Answer (score 0):

А мне кажется, правильно. Однородное подлежащее играет свою роль.

Answer (score 0):

По тому же правилу стилистики:
-Множественное число возможно и при некоторых других подлежащих, в таком случае сказуемое подчеркнуто относится к каждому из подлежащих: Ей нравились его прямота и непринужденность (Т.). 
-Однако в деловой речи предпочитается форма множественного числа, например: На пушной аукцион были выставлены каракуль и лисьи шкурки; ...Строятся завод, электростанция и несколько комплексов;
Может, наше предложение - фраза из репортажа. Тогда надо использовать сказуемое во мн.ч.

Answer (score 0):

Тогда надо изменить изменить предложение на другое: "Утром началИСЬ заезд и регистрация...". Два подлежащих относятся к одному сказуемому, следовательно, сказуемое должно стоять во множественном числе.